# What is the appropriate way to handle warning: "The expression of type x is boxed into x"

Tags: java, eclipse, autoboxing

I'm **not** looking to to turn off or ignore the warning as in [The expression of type x is boxed into X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039105/the-expression-of-type-x-is-boxed-into-x).

I'd like to know what the correct way to handle/avoid this warning is if one was so inclined.

Comment: I tend to agree with Jeffrey about "turn off the warning".  Eclipse lists this warning under "Potential programming problems", according to the link you included; but I don't see it as a source of problems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing are operations you *can* do by hand, but they're build into the language to avoid the repetition you will undoubtedly encounter.

```
Integer obj = Integer.valueOf(5); // instead of Integer obj = 5;
int i = obj.intValue(); // instead of int i = obj;
```

In my opinion, the appropriate way to handle that warning to turn it off. But if that is not an option, you can do the above.

Comment: Manual unboxing has one advantage though : explicit dereferencing of a potentially null pointer.

Comment: @Keats It's not much of an advantage. Either way, if `obj` was `null`, you are going to get a `NullPointerException`. I guess in this case it's a bit more obvious where it's coming from.

Comment: @Jeffery What I mean is that with automatic unboxing, you might forget about the possible NPE, while doing it manually forces you to think a about it. That's the purpose of the OP warning : still forcing you to think about the NPE even if you're using automatic unboxing.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion its better to explicitly box-unbox the values as it makes the code more readable.
Also there might be subtle differences when we use different approaches to boxing. For eg,

```
Integer i = new Integer(1);

Integer j = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

According to javadoc `Integer.valueOf()` caches objects so `i==j` will return `false`.

Also another way to explicitly box a primitive to Integer is

`Integer k = (Integer)1;` but this actually calls `Integer.valueOf()`.

Comment: @bn. I agree with this answer, in my opinion it is better to explicitly box-unbox. In addition to making the code more clear, it makes sure you never run into problems like the ones mentioned in the link in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19512862/2814308). Whether the likelihood of those problems is small or not is not too important for me because the price to pay to obtain this certainty (explicitly boxing-unboxing) is extremely low.