# The expression of type long is boxed into Long

Tags: java, type-conversion, autoboxing

I am having a method

```
public double getNumberOfBooks(final int count, final double Price,
        final Long Quantity, final double totalValue)
```

Now I am calling this method from other java class as mentioned below

```
public void testgetNumberOfBooks()
{
    Long obj = Long.valueOf(5l);
    long val1 = obj.longValue();

    //long val = 100L;

    final double percentageDiscountComp = 
         testClass.getNumberOfBooks(10, 900.00d, val1, 1000.00d);

}
```

But not able to pass the value of Long in argument.It's giving error as The expression of type long is boxed into Long.

Comment: I am not getting this error in my IDE, maybe its just a warning message. Perhaps it is better to pass just the obj in the arguments why at all unbox it ?

Comment: It isn't an error.  It is a warning, and you can ignore it / turn it off.  However, there is a point to it.  Namely you appear to have declare a parameter as `Long` that possibly ought to be `long`.  Unless there is a good reason to use `Long`, then that is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

No errors in intellij-idea. It might me settings of your Eclipse. Found similar error message in this question: [The expression of type x is boxed into X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039105/the-expression-of-type-x-is-boxed-into-x)

Comment: There's no error or warning in Eclipse either (Mars 2)

Comment: So maybe is depends on default settings of different Eclipse versions.